# read all comments in excel using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am trying to read an excel file which has lots of comments.
what i would like to do is to get all cells with comments using pytonic way.
the only thing i found was how to add, resize, etc comments to excel
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_comments2.html

I cant find a way to search all comments in excel.

can someone throw me a way of do it?

Comment: In Excel VBA you would get a range consisting of all cells which contain comments in a worksheet by `ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)`  (where `ws` is a worksheet variable). If `xlsxwriter` doesn't have a Python wrapper for the `SpecialCells` method then you might be out of luck and would need to loop through cells looking for comments or find a Python library which implements more of the Excel object model.

Comment: David, [`XlsxWriter` is a Python module for **creating** Excel XLSX files](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html), I'd be surprised if it comes out that you can use it to **read** such files... There is _plenty_ of Python modules to read excel files, google for "python read excel"